# How to customize filepond style in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

I want to do customize filepond uploader using react, already imported their default style, how customization is possible with that?

Answer (score 2):

you can create a css file and overwrite some css properties like ".filepond--drop-label", here are some examples: https://github.com/pqina/filepond-docs/blob/master/content/patterns/API/style.md